# Quotient groups of D10

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

How do I find the groups D10/N where N is the normal subgroups to D10?

I know that the definition is aN for all a $\in$ D10. But I am unsure what the group, for example, D10/ D10 looks like? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: $D_{10} / D_{10}$ is the set of all cosets of the form $gD_{10}$ where $g \in D_{10}$. But there is only one such coset, namely $D_{10}$ itself. So this is the trivial group. Indeed in general, the quotient group $G/G$ is trivial for any group $G$.

Comment: To answer your first question, can you list all of the normal subgroups of $D_{10}$?

Comment: thank you, all the normal subgroups of D10 are {e}, <s> (where s is the rotation about each vertex and the order of s is 5) and D10 itself

Comment: For my own edification, is this for pentagons, or decagons?

Comment: basically , this question relates to finding the possible images of f, a homomorphism, of D10 to some other group H. So if I find D10/N I find the images of f.

Comment: OK, great. Now what are the orders of $D_{10} / N$ for each of those choices of $N$ (namely $\{e\}$, $\langle s\rangle$, and $D_{10}$)?

Comment: pentagons - im not allowed to just comment that so I am writing this :)

Comment: as in the order of the group? well if D10/D10 = D10, then 10. D10/{e} = D10, so 10 and I am not sure about D10/<s>

Comment: In general, the order of $G/H$ is $|G|/|H|$ (assuming we are working with finite groups). So $D_{10}/D_{10}$ has order $|D_{10}|/|D_{10}| = 10/10 = 1$, hence it is the trivial group. Similarly, $D_{10}/\{e\}$ has order $10/1 = 10$. What about $D_{10}/\langle s\rangle$?

Comment: so the order of the group relates to the number of left cosets? anyway, the order of D10/<s> = |D10|/|<s>| = 2. therefore since 2 is a prime, it is a cyclic group? but there are 4 subgroups that have order 2?

Comment: The quotient group is exactly the set of left cosets, so the order of the quotient group equals the number of left cosets. There is in fact only one group (up to isomorphism) of order $2$, and it is indeed cyclic, as is any group of prime order. So $D_{10}/\langle s\rangle$ is cyclic of order $2$.

Comment: Your statement "there are 4 subgroups of order 2" makes me suspect that you mistakenly believe that a quotient group $G/H$ is a subgroup of $G$. This is a common error when learning about quotient groups. A quotient group is NOT a subgroup of $G$. It is a group of *cosets* of $H$. In some situations, there may be a subgroup of $G$ which is *isomorphic* to $G/H$, but this need not always be the case. In general, there may not even be a subgroup of $G$ with the same *order* as $G/H$.

Comment: I did, indeed, think that! so I know that D10/<s> = {<s>, t<s>}. So the D10/D10 gives us the trivial answer but what is that? is that just {e} then? Please can you tell me what all of them look like, I would be so grateful - you have taught me sooo much so far :D

Comment: I'll go ahead and post an answer as the comments are getting cluttered and you have mostly worked it out now.

Comment: thank you so much! what a star you are :D

Answer (score 1):

The standard reference (on this site at least) for dihedral groups are the [notes](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/dihedral2.pdf) by K. Conrad. Theorem $2.3$ and its proof answers the question. All quotients $D_{10}/N$ are again dihedral groups. All normal subgroups of $D_{10}$ are listed in Theorem $3.8$.

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing the comments:

In general, a quotient group $G/N$ is a group consisting of the cosets of $N$, under the multiplication rule $(aH)(bH) = abH$. This is a valid group if and only if $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

In your case, $G = D_{10}$ is the dihedral group with $10$ elements. As you noted, it has three normal subgroups, namely $\{e\}$, $G$, and $\langle s\rangle$, where the latter is the rotation subgroup of order $5$. Now, $G$ and $\{e\}$ are always normal in any group. And in this particular group, $\langle s \rangle$ is normal because it has index $2$.

Let us examine each of the quotient groups.

1. If $N = G$ then $G/N = G/G$. This group has order $|G| / |N| = |G| / |G| = 10 / 10 = 1$, i.e., it is the trivial group. It contains one element, which is the coset $G$ itself. We may write $G/G = \{G\}$ if we want to list the elements explicitly.
2. If $N = \{e\}$, then $G/N = G/\{e\}$. This group has order $|G| / |\{e\}| = 10 / 1 = 10$. So the group contains $10$ elements. They are the cosets of $\{e\}$, each of which is of the form $g\{e\}$ for some $g \in G$. Moreover, distinct elements $g,h \in G$ give us distinct cosets $g\{e\}$ and $h\{e\}$. There is an obvious isomorphism between this group of cosets and the original group itself: just map $g \in G$ to $g\{e\} \in G/\{e\}$. So, in this case, $G/N = G/\{e\}$ is isomorphic to $G$ itself.
3. If $N = \langle s\rangle$ then $G/N = G/\langle s\rangle$. This group has order $|G| / |\langle s\rangle| = 10 / 5 = 2$. So the group contains $2$ elements. They are the cosets of $\langle s \rangle$. One of these cosets is $\langle s \rangle$ itself. The other can be expressed as $g \langle s \rangle$ where $g$ is any element of $G$ which is not in $\langle s \rangle$. Note that any group of order $2$ (or more generally, any prime number) is cyclic, so there is only one group (up to isomoprhism) of this order. Therefore $G/N$ is cyclic of order $2$.

One more thing to emphasize: as mentioned in the comments, a quotient group $G/N$ is **not** a subgroup of $G$. This is a common misconception when first learning about quotient groups. Rather, $G/N$ is a separate group, formed from the cosets of $N$. You can think of it as looking at the group $G$ through eyeglasses which "blur" your vision in such a way that $N$ looks like a single "element" instead of being composed of individual elements.

In some cases, $G$ will contain a subgroup which is **isomoprhic** to $G/N$, but in general this is not the case. Indeed, in general, $G$ need not even contain a subgroup with the same **order** as $G/N$.